# Steps required to set up a new website using Apache (after purchase of a domain name)

Tags: domain, apache-2.2, website

Although I have been through the steps required to setup a website, after aquisition of a domain name, I have forgotten the steps required. I have a couple of domain names which I purchased a while back and I want to setup 'coming soon' type pages for them.

I am already running a website with my hosting provider (using Apache), and there are no restrictions (within reasons ofcourse) on how many websites I can set up on my server (its a VPS).

Unfortunately, I do not recall the steps involved.

Could someonne please remind me the steps required so that I can have the new websites www.website1.com and www.website2.com setup to coexist peacefully with www.myexistingsite.com on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the nameservers of your domain to point to your hosting account nameservers.
2. Add the domain to your hosting account as a subdomain if you are only allowed to have one main domain. If you have a cPanel interface this is quite simple and you can setup the url to you new domain as www.domain.com. cPanel will create the required directory in you public_html folder and all relevant files.
3. Optionally you can choose to have a 301 permanent redirect from your subdomain domain.maindomain.com to www.domain.com if someone ever wanted to access your new site using the subdomain